# how to access controller vars within controllerAs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controlleras

i kickstart an app with yeoman, who use "controllerAs" to initiate the app.js..

i know that in this way i don't use the **$scope**, but i have to use **this** to access to controller proprieties, but in somehow i'm not able to visualize the changes... somebody can help me?

Here what i have done:

**app.js**

```
            angular
              .module('viaggiApp', [
                'ngAnimate',
                'ngCookies',
                'ngResource',
                'ngRoute',
                'ngTouch',
                'ngMaps'
              ])
              .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                  .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'main'    
                  })
                  .when('/about', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'about'
                  })
                  .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                  });
                   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');      
              });
```

**controller (Main)**

```
 angular.module('viaggiApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($q,GetPathGoogle,NgMap) {
this.propriety="say hi";
});
```

**html**

```
{{main.propriety}}
```

why the html don't render properly the propriety value, but it show me the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
  app.controller("namesctrl", function(){
            this.propriety="say hi";
  });
  
 </script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl as ctrl">
{{ctrl.propriety}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have kickstarted the app using yeoman, (can't replicate your structure) what i have changed now is to link the controller in the main.html like this:

<div class="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"> 
 {{main.propriety}}
</div>

but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
   <h1> {{main.propriety}} </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: i have done this:
<div class="row" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main"> 
 {{main.propriety}}
</div>
but nothing.. i'm wonder if could be a yeoman problem...